# Backbone-relational Belongs To

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

How do you create and use belongs to (or many to one) relations using backbone and backbone-relational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your relationship is, for instance, A Building has many Rooms.  A Room belongs to a Building:

```
Building = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: 'HasMany',
            key: 'rooms',
            relatedModel: 'Room',
            reverseRelation: {
                key: 'building'
            }
        }
    ]
});

Room = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend();

house = new Building({id:1});
science_building = new Building({id:2});

console.log(house.get('rooms').length);  // ==> 0

living_room = new Room({building:1,name:"Living Room"});
lab = new Room({building:2,name:"Chemistry Lab"});

console.log(house.get('rooms').length); // ==> 1
console.log(house.get('rooms').first().get('name')); // ==> "Living Room"

console.log(science_building.get('rooms').length); // ==> 1
console.log(science_building.get('rooms').first().get('name')); // ==> "Chemistry Lab"
```

The reverseRelation property specifies the "belongs_to" part of the relationship.

Comment: I thought I need to define relation in Room model as well, but it finds it automatically. So `lab.get('building')` will return science_building. Thanks

Comment: this answer finally made me get backbone relational. thank you!